# Hilt - EntryPoint in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt for DI and I have this class.

```
class ChatCore @Inject constructor()
```

This class needs to be injected in fragment , without marking the fragment as `@AdroidEntryPoint` as this fragment can be attached to activity which isn't marked as `@AndroidEntryPoint`

How can i achieve this. I tried using EntryPoint  but i end up with error.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

  lateinit var chatCore: ChatCore 

  @EntryPoint
  @InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
  interface ChatCoreProviderEntryPoint{
    fun chatCore():ChatCore
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromFragment(this, ChatCoreProviderEntryPoint::class.java)
    chatCore = hiltEntryPoint.chatCore()
  }
```

---

Solved it by adding it into the application container.

```
      @EntryPoint
      @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
      interface ChatCoreProviderEntryPoint{
        fun chatCore():ChatCore
      }


      val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(applicationContext,
         ChatCoreProviderEntryPoint::class.java)
```

Comment: Worked by using EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `AndroidEntryPoint` for your `Fragment` you need to `@Install` your module (containing your dependency) within a different `Component`.
E.g. within the `ApplicationComponent` not the `FragmentComponent`.

Then you will also need to use the corresponding `EntryPointAccessors.fromXyz(...)` method. E.g. for a module installed in the `ApplicationComponent` you should be using `EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(...)`.

Comment: Yeah. I realized it later and got it fixed after putting it in the application component, i had updated my answer.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, didn't notice that. You should've posted an answer of your own instead of adding an edit to your question.

Comment: Ohh okay. sorry for the confusion. Thanks for giving detailed answer!